# How to set default value for Auto-Implemented Properties in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, default-value, automatic-properties

I came to know that C# 3.0 comes with a new feature of Auto-Implemented Properties,I liked it as we don't have to declare extra private varible in this (compare to earlier property),  earlier I was using a Property i.e.

```
private bool isPopup = true;
public bool IsPopup
{
    get
    {
      return isPopup;
    }
    set
    {
      isPopup = value;
    }
}
```

Now I've converted it into Auto-Implemented property i.e.

```
public bool IsPopup
{
    get; set;
}
```

I want to set the default value of this property to true without using it not even in page_init method, I tried but not succeeded, Can anyone explain how to do this?

Comment: Initialize it in the constructor

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can initialize the property in the default constructor:

```
public MyClass()
{
   IsPopup = true;
}
```

With C# 6.0 it is possible to initialize the property at the declaration like normal member fields:

```
public bool IsPopup { get; set; } = true;  // property initializer
```

It is now even possible to create a real read-only automatic property which you can either initialize directly or in the constructor, but not set in other methods of the class.

```
public bool IsPopup { get; } = true;  // read-only property with initializer
```

Comment: Thanks , I think thats the only way.

Comment: Looking for more specific answers , for this I have to write additional code in constructor , is there no way to write it in the Auto-implemented property itself, without using old conventions.

Comment: Somehow you have to initialize your property. As there is no backing field (it's generated by the compiler), there is no other option. Under these circumstances I write the full properties, fortunately you get intellisense to do this.

Comment: @slfan Can you elaborate? I am starting to use auto's and am trying to understand fundamentals. Your answer made sense, but then your comment (as I read it) seems to contradict it- I'm sure I am misunderstanding what you are saying in that comment though as your answer wouldn't be correct and have upvotes.

Comment: At the moment this is the only way. In the coming C# 6.0 there will be the possibility to directly initialize the property. I use full properties only when I have to write code in the setter or getter.

Answer (score 8):

Attributes specified for an auto property do not apply to the backing field, so an attribute for a default value won't work for this type of property.

You can, however, initialize an auto property:

**VB.NET**

```
Property FirstName As String = "James"
Property PartNo As Integer = 44302
Property Orders As New List(Of Order)(500)
```

**C# 6.0 and above**

```
public string FirstName { get; set; } = "James";
public int PartNo { get; set; } = 44302;
public List<Order> Orders { get; set; } = new List<Order>(500);
```

**C# 5.0 and below**

Unfortunately, C# versions below 6.0 do not support this, so you have to initialize the default values for auto properties in the constructor.

Comment: Good edit Eagle-Eye, thanks for updating this to include C# 6.0.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried  [DefaultValueAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.defaultvalueattribute.aspx)

Comment: Ok so I found out that this was not the correct way.It seems that DefaultValueAttribute just instructs the meta data that a property can have a default value and does not actually set it.So I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.ComponentModel;

[DefaultValue(true)]
public bool IsPopup
{
    get
    {
      return isPopup;
    }
    set
    {
      isPopup = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: did you see the answer by Akshat Jeewan Sharma?

Comment: Was it "Copy and paste"?

Comment: see @Jeewan Sharma 's answer to understand this is not the right way to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **default property value** like below

**One advantage** of this method is you **don't need to check null values** for **Boolean** types

```
using System.ComponentModel; 

public class ClassName
 {
   [DefaultValue(true)]
   public bool IsPopup{ get; set; }
 }
```

Comment: That doesn't actually set the default value, it just indicates what the default value should be

Comment: @JoeFlateau could you explain what is the difference of both methods?B'cos when I access that property from controller its value is true.So then ?

Comment: DefaultValue is purely informational, Visual Studio will show the value as not bold.