# Errors on vb property variables when I build a project

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net

The company I work for recently had a programmer leave and he did a WPF project in VB that is no longer working. I have been assigned to fix the project. The first thing I notice are the build errors on these property variables he has. They look like this

```
Public Property BasePath As String = "this is a string to db properties"
Public Property header As New CurrentRun_HDR
Public Property PageHolder As New List(Of Page)
Public Property ScheduleHolder As New List(Of Page)
Public Property HeaderHolder As New List(Of Page)
Private Property LastUpdate As DateTime = Now
Private Property RefreshDate As DateTime = Now
Public Property MouseEnabled As Boolean = True
```

Visual Studio 2008 is saying that properties need a get, set so I satisfied the first one by doing something like this.

```
Private _Prop2 As String = "this is a string to db properties"
    Property BasePath() As String
        Get
            Return _Prop2
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _Prop2 = value
        End Set
    End Property
```

I am not sure how to fix the other errors like the next one

`Public Property header As New CurrentRun_HDR` it is saying new is not a valid in this context. When I googled this it says you can do auto implemented properties like this code is doing but they are throwing errors on the build any help would be greatly appreciated. I am using .Net Framework 3.5 with Visual Studio 2008

I have been to this [site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/auto-implemented-properties)

Comment: I think that auto-implement properties were introduced with VS 2010, so how did that ever compile?

Comment: @Plutonix correct - auto-implement properties were added in VS 2010.

Comment: interesting I am not sure but I will try to open it in vs2010 and see what happens. The guy just said they used vs 2008 and I took their word for it

Answer (score -1):

The syntax should be something along these lines:

```
Public Property PageHolder As List(Of Page) = New List(Of Page)
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8293918/how-to-set-default-value-for-auto-implemented-properties-in-asp-net) for more examples.

Comment: Not useful: this doesn't address the Visual Studio version incompatibility, and it's more verbose than the roughly equivalent syntax that was used above.  `Public Property ... As New List(Of ...)` is perfectly cromulent.